# Boolean object is not working properly in condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I´m really confused. Maybe anyone can help me?
The problem is the following:

```
var isSignInside = new Boolean(someCondition);

if (!isSignInside) {
    //doStuff
}
else {
    //doOtherStuff
}
```

Now, if `isSignInside` is `false` (the debugger told me), the script still jumps to `//doOtherStuff`. How can this be?
The rest of the snippet isn´t of relevance, but I can share it if asked.
Surely there is an easy explanation i don´t see. Thanks in advance.
**Edit:**
The someCondition really is a custom method "forced" to return a bool instead of (otherwise) a string.
**Edit:** Just used the function directly in the if. Needed some tricky paranthesis, but works now. Thanks for the hint that a (boolean) object can never be === to a static boolean primitive. Hell this forum is fast.

Comment: `if (!someCondition) { //doStuff } else { //doOtherStuff }`

Comment: `new Boolean()` creates an object, and object is always going to be true.  you just need to check your condition directly.. eg.  `if (!someCondition)`

Comment: The very first example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean describies exactly this case.

Comment: funny title, javascript never works actually, browsers do it (or don't)

Comment: tl;dr do `Boolean(someCondition)` instead of `new Boolean(someCondition)`

Comment: Try `if (isSignInside + 0)`. The `+ 0` will force the Boolean object to be coerced to its primitive value.

Comment: @torazaburo isnt it rather toNumber() ?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a Boolean object, it's an **object**. A reference to it, regardless of the boolean primitive value it represents, will always test as truthy just like any other non-null object reference.

There's generally no point in constructing a Boolean instance like that:

```
var isSignInside = !!someCondition;
```

That'll give you a boolean primitive that reflects the truthy/falsy state of your condition.

Comment: your answer would be better if you explained how to make the code work in addition to explaining why it won't.

Comment: This is the correct answer but you might want to expand on it so OP can understand

Comment: @BryanOakley done

Comment: it is also common to use `Boolean(someCondition)`

Comment: No, i also tried === false. Didn´t work either.

Comment: @Damon yes that'd work too but I don't like typing :)

Comment: @L.Riemer that's because no object reference is `===` to the boolean primitive constant `false`.

Comment: never seen any reason to use Boolean object, and this post doesn't convince to ever use it :P well, i guess there are rare cases..

Answer (score 2):

```
if(new Boolean(false)) alert("hehe");
```

Actually, *isSignedInside* is not a boolean, but a boolean object (thanks to the *new*). You may want to get its primitive value for comparison:

```
if( (new Boolean(false)).valueOf() ) alert("hehe");
```

Or even easier, take the value directly.

Comment: Visualizing same concept from debugger: http://imgur.com/a/zRbUb

Answer (score 1):

Well that's not how that's done. You want to use a boolean primitive. What you're trying to do is done this way:

```
var isSignInside = (someCondition);
if (isSignInside === false) {
   //doStuff
}
else {
    //doOtherStuff
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/catbadger/pxrteq59/

Comment: No. Negating it is probably better then strict equality to false

Comment: That´s the point. As i just learned `!(new Boolean(false))` does evaluate to false.

Comment: @Jonasw defend your statement. negation is ambiguous

Comment: @catbager !isSignedIn

Comment: that is ambiguous. if it's not equal to false but zero, your statement will evaluate to true.